# Unable to Insert ContentVersion record as a Community User in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, sharing

I'm unable to create ContentVersion records running a test class as a Partner Community user. I have created a Partner user using the same methods displaying in the test class, tested the process manually and works properly. It is annoying since it's only failing in the test class. I'm using a public class and I have granted access to all the involved objects and fields.

Error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You do not have
>   the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested.
>   Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access
>   is necessary.: [NetworkId]

Fragment of the Test Class:

```
static testMethod void uploadFiles() {

    //Creating Broker Data
    Account partnerAcc = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateAccount();
    partnerAcc.IsPartner = true;
    update partnerAcc;
    Contact partnerCon = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateContact(partnerAcc.Id);
    User contactUser = TestDataFactoryCls.createUserFromContact(partnerCon, 'Partner Community Clone');
    //Creating Data Owned by the Broker
    Account acct = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateAccount();
    Contact contact = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateContact(acct.Id);
    Opportunity opp1 = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateOpportunity(acct.Id, contact.Id,'fixed investor v5', 'Asset', 'Purchase', 'Closed Won', partnerCon.Id, partnerAcc.Id);
    Opportunity opp2 = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateOpportunity(acct.Id, contact.Id,'fixed investor v5', 'Asset', 'Refi', 'Application', partnerCon.Id, partnerAcc.Id);
    System.debug('opp2 before ' + opp2.StageName + ' ' + opp2.AFS_Referrer_Name__c + ' ' + opp2.Broker_Contact__c);
    List<Loan_Doc_Sort__c> lds = [SELECT Id, Loan_Documentation__c, Loan__c, Document__c, Comment_History__c, Comment__c, Status__c FROM Loan_Doc_Sort__c WHERE Loan__c = :opp2.Id];
    Loan_Doc_Sort__c ld1 = lds[0];

    System.runAs(contactUser) {           
       ContentVersion cv3 = new ContentVersion();
       cv3.title = 'test content trigger';      
       cv3.PathOnClient ='test';           
       cv3.VersionData =Blob.valueOf('Test Content'); 
       cv3.FirstPublishLocationId =  ld1.Id;        
       insert cv3;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ld1`? It's not declared here. Can you confirm which line throws the exception?

Comment: Edited the original question. Added ld1 which is an instance of a custom object child of the Opportunity, multiple of these are created when an opportunity is inserted. The line throwing the error is the last line: 'insert cv3'. Thanks

Comment: What's the type of relationship between that object and Opportunity? What's the OWD on that object?

Comment: It is a Master-Detail, the OWD is is "Controlled by Parent", the Community profile have Read,, Create, Edit over the parent object (Opportunity)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The community user should have access to `Loan_Doc_Sort__c` record to upload files on it.

You have few options,

1. Change the OWD of `Loan_Doc_Sort__c` to public read-only external
2. Create a manual share record for `Loan_Doc_Sort__c` after insert and
   share it with the commnunity user.
3. Ensure The community user is the one creating the `Loan_Doc_Sort__c` in the test class

   ```
   static testMethod void uploadFiles() {
   //Creating Broker Data
   Account partnerAcc = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateAccount();
   partnerAcc.IsPartner = true;
   update partnerAcc;
   Contact partnerCon = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateContact(partnerAcc.Id);
   User contactUser = TestDataFactoryCls.createUserFromContact(partnerCon, 'Partner Community Clone');
   //Creating Data Owned by the Broker
   System.runAs(contactUser) {           
       Account acct = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateAccount();
       Contact contact = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateContact(acct.Id);
       Opportunity opp1 = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateOpportunity(acct.Id, contact.Id,'fixed investor v5', 'Asset', 'Purchase', 'Closed Won', partnerCon.Id, partnerAcc.Id);
       Opportunity opp2 = TestDataFactoryCls.CreateOpportunity(acct.Id, contact.Id,'fixed investor v5', 'Asset', 'Refi', 'Application', partnerCon.Id, partnerAcc.Id);
       System.debug('opp2 before ' + opp2.StageName + ' ' + opp2.AFS_Referrer_Name__c + ' ' + opp2.Broker_Contact__c);
       List<Loan_Doc_Sort__c> lds = [SELECT Id, Loan_Documentation__c, Loan__c, Document__c, Comment_History__c, Comment__c, Status__c FROM Loan_Doc_Sort__c WHERE Loan__c = :opp2.Id];
       Loan_Doc_Sort__c ld1 = lds[0];
       ContentVersion cv3 = new ContentVersion();
       cv3.title = 'test content trigger';      
       cv3.PathOnClient ='test';           
       cv3.VersionData =Blob.valueOf('Test Content'); 
       cv3.FirstPublishLocationId =  ld1.Id;        
       insert cv3;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: My external sharing settings were set to "private", created a sharing rule since I didn't want to modify the OWD. Thanks for the response.

Comment: It is very late to ask. I am also getting the same error. My ContentVersion is getting inserted in the apex class having Without sharing. Also, OWD for External USer for Account is public read/write. On the profile, it is Read and edit. When running test class in Portal user context not able to insert the ContentVersion. Checked to debug the same portal user is coming to run the method having the DML. When I try to do the unit test from customer portal it is working fine. Any thoughts